# Use LINQ to select elements within a generic list and casting to their specific type

Tags: linq

I have a base class, called `NodeUpgrade`, which have several child types. An example of a specific child class is `FactoryUpgrade`.

I have a list of NodeUpgrades, which can be a mix of different child types. How do I write a linq query to retrieve a type of `NodeUpgrade` and cast to that specific type?

My working query looks something like this:

```
var allFactories = (from Node n in assets.Nodes
                    from FactoryUpgrade u in n.NodeUpgrades
                    where u.ClassID == NodeUpgradeTypes.Factory
                    select u)
```

This, of course, doesn't work. Can I specify the final type of the output?

Comment: is the syntax right ? what is u ?

Comment: Thanks, I missed out the variable name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure that every type in a sequence is a given type, you can use the `Cast<T>()` extension method. If there can be multiple types in the list and you only want one of them, you can use `OfType<T>()` to filter the sequence.

```
List<Animal> animals = ...

// assumes all animals are cats 
var cats = animals.Cast<Cat>();
// var cats = (from animal in animals where ... select animal).Cast<Cat>();

// or maybe animals can contain dogs, but you don't want them
var cats = animals.OfType<Cat>();
```

The difference is that `Cast` will throw an exception if an animal *isn't* a cat, whereas `OfType` will perform a type check before actually trying the conversion. I would favor `Cast` over `OfType` when you are confident of the uniform type. (Also note that these **do not** perform user-defined conversions. If you have defined an implicit or explicit conversion, those will not be supported by these methods.)

The resulting sequence in each case will be `IEnumerable<Cat>`, which you can do further query operations on (filters, groupings, projections, `ToList()`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [OfType<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
var allFactories = (from Node n in assets.Nodes
                    from FactoryUpgrade in n.NodeUpgrades
                    where u.ClassID == NodeUpgradeTypes.Factory
                    select u).OfType<ChildType>();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use the .OfType extension method to filter the types (assuming you have set the inheritance model and appropriate discriminators on your data source). This will translate in the database to include the appropriate Where clause on the discriminator (ClassID).

```
var allFactories = from n in assets.Nodes 
                   from u in n.NodeUpgrades.OfType<FactoryUpgrade>() 
                   select u;
```

You didn't specify here if you were using EF, LINQ to SQL, or just Linq to Objects in this case. Each has a different way of modeling the inheritance. If you need help with the modeling portion, let us know which OR/M you are using.